# How to best compress timeseries into a different duration?

Tags: r, time-series

I've got a timeseries object defined like so:

```
tser <- ts(cumsum(1 + rnorm(48)), frequency = 12, start = c(2010, 1))
```

The data looks similar to the below (clipped to only show one year)

```
        Jan        Feb        Mar        Apr        May        Jun        Jul        Aug        Sep        Oct        Nov        Dec
  2010  0.6055677  2.8650543  2.6115597  3.1496051  2.6611612  4.4993758  6.0717509  6.9426434  7.1386547  7.1653957  8.2570628  7.8585075
```

I would like to roll this data up into quarterly data.  So I'd only see one value for each quarter.

is there a recommend way of doing this other than walking through each month and aggregating myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `aggregate.ts` with `sum`, `mean` or whatever summary function desired.  See `?aggregate.ts`

```
> aggregate(tser, 4, sum)
          Qtr1      Qtr2      Qtr3      Qtr4
2010  10.21558  15.22923  21.98924  30.94460
2011  39.81982  45.00208  61.26129  73.03194
2012  87.63780  97.27455 104.69757 115.09325
2013 126.71070 138.39925 145.47344 159.00137
```

Comment: Can I assume you mean aggregate.ts(tser, 4, sum)instead of (aggregate(tser, 4, sum)?

Comment: No. We call the generic `aggregate` and let it invoke the particular method `aggregate.ts`.